# Escape encode all character within pre tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, escaping

I am looking to escape all code within the `<pre>` tags so I can display it to the browser.

Here is what I am trying to do...

```
<pre><code>
  Code below
   <?php
     if ( $is_iphone ) { ?>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; initial-scale=0.9; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
   <?php } ?>
</pre></code>
```

I am looking to use jQuery to do this. Is there a function?

So the output would be.

```
<pre><code>
  Code below
    &lt;?php
      if ( $is_iphone ) { ?&gt;
        &lt;meta name="viewport" content="width=320; initial-scale=0.9; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" /&gt;
    &lt;?php } ?&gt; 
</pre></code>
```

Can you do this with jQuery?

Here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() 
    {

    $("#teatarea").keyup(function() 
    {
    var textarea=$(this).val();

    // I can change this function to text instead of HTML but I need the <pre> tags to stay as HTML to display to the browser???

    $(".addesc1").html(textarea);

    return false;
    });

    });
</script> `
```

HTML:

```
<div id="dis" class="addesc1">
  Description Line 1
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need to do this on the client? Is there a reason for not just doing it at the PHP end? It may even be a security risk to do it on the client if you have no control over the code being put onto the page.

Comment: hi i am trying to just use it to do a quick form preview similar to the one on this website.

Comment: You have to close your tags in the order they're nested: `<pre><code>content</code></pre>`

Answer (score 1):

as you have asked for the textarea with php i have done it here is the demo http://fiddle.jshell.net/3y4qA/1/

you cannot  retrive php with jquery as you have asked but you can try to post it via ajax and get the value